# Trying to appendChild an user input and a button element into the same <li>

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to get a event planner app to show some user input and subsequently allow them to delete it when needed.

i have the input part working, but i can't figure out how to get a button with "delete" added to the same li when the user presses Enter.

this is my JS so far: (what do i need to add to get the button included in the li)

```js
function todoList(){
    const item: string = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('todoInput')).value;
    const text = document.createTextNode(item)
    const newItem = document.createElement('li')

    const button: any = document.createElement("button")
    button.innerHTML = 'Delete';

    newItem.appendChild(text)

    // @ts-ignore
}

const form = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('todoForm'))
form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

})
```

```html
<h1 class="title">todos</h1>
<form id="todoForm" onsubmit="todoList()" >
    <button  id="scrolldown-menu-toggle">˅</button>
    <input type="text" id="todoInput" placeholder="Fill in your plan">
</form>


<ol id="todoList">
</ol>
```

Comment: I can see you are appending the text node to your list item but not the button. Also your snippet is not running due to some error.

Comment: I have left out the appending of the button in the example as i could not get it to run. For example i tried - newitem.appendchild(text + button) but i got an error.

Comment: alright. I have posted an answer that seems to adress the issue. When you post a snippet with modern JS you need to tick the ecmascript2015 box in snippet settings for it to play. But I could not get the <> annotation to work in my snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the button into the `<li>` as well.
So you would want to do this -

```
function todoList(){
   const item: string = 
(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('todoInput')).value;
   const text = document.createTextNode(item)
   const newItem = document.createElement('li')

   const button: any = document.createElement("button")
   button.innerHTML = 'Delete';

   newItem.appendChild(text)
   newItem.appendChild(button) // <--- Add this line
   

   // @ts-ignore
}
```

Comment: This worked! thanks so much, this helps me out a lot. i imagine  can use the same principle to add even more elements to the same li!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```js
function todoList() {
  // <HTMLInputElement> removed as the snippet will not run otherwise.
  // This does however not seem to affect the execution of the code.
  
  // Read the input text into variable:
  const item: string = (document.getElementById('todoInput')).value;  
  
  // Create text-node:
  const text = document.createTextNode(item);
  
  // Create list item:
  const newItem = document.createElement('li');
  
  // Create button:
  const button: any = document.createElement("button");
  
  // Create button text node and append it to button:
  const btnText = document.createTextNode('Delete');
  button.appendChild(btnText);

  // Add handler to actually delete the entry:
  button.addEventListener('click', e => newItem.remove());
  
  // Append text and button to the list item:
  newItem.appendChild(text);
  newItem.appendChild(button);
  
  // Append list item to the ordered list:
  document.getElementById('todoList').appendChild(newItem);

  // @ts-ignore
}

const form = (document.getElementById('todoForm'))
form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

```html
<h1 class="title">todos</h1>
<form id="todoForm" onsubmit="todoList()">
  <button id="scrolldown-menu-toggle" type="submit">˅</button>
  <input type="text" id="todoInput" placeholder="Fill in your plan" />
</form>

<ol id="todoList">
</ol>
```

Comment: apreciated! the addition of the (delete) event listener will prove very usefull too. thanks so much!